# youtube_dl error: Failed to parse JSON (caused by JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')) disocrd error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl, ytdl

Error:

youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: query "song": Failed to parse JSON (caused by JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')

Play command:

```py
    @commands.command(name='play',aliases=['p'] )
    async def _play(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, search: str):
        async with ctx.typing():
            try:
                source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop)
            except YTDLError as e:
                await ctx.send('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
            else:
                song = Song(source)

                await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
```

Youtube-DL Class:

```py
class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    YTDL_OPTIONS = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'extractaudio': True,
        'audioformat': 'mp3',
        'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'restrictfilenames': True,
        'noplaylist': True,
        'nocheckcertificate': True,
        'ignoreerrors': False,
        'logtostderr': False,
        'quiet': True,
        'no_warnings': True,
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'source_address': '0.0.0.0',
    }

    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
        'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
        'options': '-vn',
    }

    ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YTDL_OPTIONS)
```

Please guide me how to fix this error This error started for me last week and my youtube_dl is also updated

If you need another code, tell me, but please fix my problem

I also do not know how to get error message including stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) was taken down, which means that it's not accessible to public anymore.

Instead of directly using `youtube-dl`, you can use libraries like [`pafy`](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/) that uses the command-line version of `youtube-dl`:

```py
from pafy import new

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx):
    ffmpeg_opts = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()

    video = new("youtube video link")
    audio = video.getbestaudio().url
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(audio, **ffmpeg_opts))
    voice.is_playing()
```

`pafy` doesn't include youtube search so you'll have to do your own. For this you have multiple choices:

- Doing some webscraping using [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
- Using libraries like [`fast-youtube-search`](https://pypi.org/project/fast-youtube-search/)
- Use [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) (which is the async version of `requests`) and [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find the video id. This last option is probably the fastest one.

If you want an easier solution, you can use [`pytube`](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but it's slower and supports up to python 3.7.

Comment: Is there any way I can use this youtube-dl?
I can even pay, no problem

Comment: No, you can't use it anymore. You can try speaking to the repository owner but I don't think this will be any useful. If you want to know why it was taken down, you can go on `youtube-dl`'s github page : https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

Comment: Thanks 
I used the second method